# What components do I need to finish my shower installation?

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture

Soooo I replaced the rough in valves for my shower ( based on some suggestions here actually ). [This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DNOV7G) is the set that I purchased. Now that it's installed, I'm noticing that the stems are shorter than the old one by about an inch. I'm also super confused about what kind of trim kit I need. Was looking at something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JFNNT6) but it seems to have both valve stems and handles, and I really don't need the stems ( right ? ). Then there is something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003EQ11L4) but it includes the whole build kit. So I'm super confused about what I need to finish this rough in kit.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the bottom of the Amazon page where it says "customers also bought this" there's trim kits there that have exactly what you're missing. Pretty typical for a contractor to use a rough in kit like you did and then let the customer pick a trim kit later. The only problem you have is you're limited to trim kits that work with the 01-31XA valve body. You should be able to find one you like. Here's one **Pfister 01-8CBC Three-Handle Tub and Shower Combo, Chrome**
Fits 01-31XA valve body
The Pfister Three-Handle Tub and Shower Trim Kit comes with classic Brass Cross Handles, flanges, bell-shaped shower head, and a threaded tub spout. The upgraded Polished Chrome finish and Brass Cross Handles is a great addition to any bathroom. Valves not included.

Comment: Just a warning - I'm not sure the Amazon recommendations for related products are always going to be compatible. I would make sure to double-check taht.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to uninstall that valve set and buy a complete faucet set. The valve set you have is if you needed to replace your valves you have and keep the original handles etc. A faucet set would have had everything you need and the proper sizes.

Comment: so you can't just buy the handles?

Comment: You can, however you would need to take that set of valve into your hardware store, in order to match it up. You would need to use the same brand or compatible brand. It would be cheaper and easier to just use a faucet kit with handles, and backsplash covers, etc.

Comment: You can also possibly look up the valve set you bought, and look for compatible matching handle set.

Comment: I think this is excessive. I wouldn't do an uninstall at this point unless there was practically no other option.